# QEMU not saving CPU Pinning for a virtual machine

Tags: linux, windows, qemu, linux-kvm, virsh

I installed a Windows 10 and Windows Server 2019 virtual machine under my Rocky Linux 9.1 KVM hypervisor. My plan for this setup is to practice system administration, and I'd like to be able to run multiple VMs at once.

I found that both Windows VMs ran pretty slow (basically unusable), so I tried some of the fixes on [improving VM guest performance](https://leduccc.medium.com/improving-the-performance-of-a-windows-10-guest-on-qemu-a5b3f54d9cf5). Windows Server 2019 runs a little better now thanks to CPU Pinning, but the problem I have now is that the Windows 10 VM will not save CPU Pinning.

Here's a picture of how my computer setup is. Windows 10 Host, running Rocky Linux KVM in Virtualbox, then Windows Server and Windows 10 in QEMU.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aurzp.png]

I've had this problem for over a month now and I've tried *many* things.

I originally assigned 8 cores to my Rocky Linux 9.1 VM, but for troubleshooting I'm now using 10 cores. For Windows Server, I assigned it 4 cores and pinned cores 0 to 3 and it works fine. For Windows 10, I assign it 4 cores and try to pin cores 4 to 7, but it never saves it. I've tried to pin different combinations of cores but it doesn't save. Strangely, if I pin the same cores used in Windows Server to the Windows 10 VM, it DOES save the CPU Pinning. But then, Windows Server doesn't have any pinned cores.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vIxT.png]

And to make sure I'm using the correct cores, here's output from lscpu -e:

```
[admin@localhost ~]$ lscpu -e
CPU NODE SOCKET CORE L1d:L1i:L2:L3 ONLINE
  0    0      0    0 0:0:0:0          yes
  1    0      0    1 1:1:1:1          yes
  2    0      0    2 2:2:2:2          yes
  3    0      0    3 3:3:3:3          yes
  4    0      0    4 4:4:4:4          yes
  5    0      0    5 5:5:5:5          yes
  6    0      0    6 6:6:6:6          yes
  7    0      0    7 7:7:7:7          yes
  8    0      0    8 8:8:8:8          yes
  9    0      0    9 9:9:9:9          yes
```

The first thing I tried to do was install VirtIO drivers and Spice Guest Tools. VirtIO drivers may have helped, but the difference is barely noticeable. Spice Guest Tools was dropped in RHEL 9 so I can't even use that.

Next, I read that the text editor could be the issue with saving edits. I switched from vim to nano (edited /etc/environment and added in `export EDITOR=nano`), ran `sudo virsh edit win10`, pinned the CPU cores, save, exit, then check the XML config file, and the changes aren't saved. Can confirm that it's not the editor because it works fine for other VMs and reads `Domain: 'win10' XML configuration edited.` after exiting.

Another thing I read was that `sudo virsh edit` won't save any changes if the VM is running. I only edit the VM's XML when it's shut off, so this isn't a cause.

Something weird that I just discovered is that I'm able to do CPU Pinning in the Windows 10 VM ONLY IF I add 4 additional cores. If I assign only 4 cores to the VM and pin those 4 cores, once I save and exit, the CPU Pinning lines disappear. It looks like this:

```
  <vcpu placement="static">4</vcpu>
  <iothreads>1</iothreads>
  <cputune>
    <emulatorpin cpuset="4"/>
    <iothreadpin iothread="1" cpuset="4"/>
  </cputune>
```

However, if I assign 8 cores (an additional 4 cores on top of the 4 already there) and pin 4 cores, once I save and exit, I still have those 4 cores pinned. It looks like this:

```
  <vcpu placement="static">8</vcpu>
  <iothreads>1</iothreads>
  <cputune>
    <vcpupin vcpu="4" cpuset="4"/>
    <vcpupin vcpu="5" cpuset="5"/>
    <vcpupin vcpu="6" cpuset="6"/>
    <vcpupin vcpu="7" cpuset="7"/>
    <emulatorpin cpuset="4"/>
    <iothreadpin iothread="1" cpuset="4"/>
  </cputune>
```

The problem with the above config is that the VM will use 8 cores instead of 4 cores. See below:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGxKF.png]

I'm not really sure what else to try. My goal is to have Windows VMs that boot up fast, work fast enough, and to not constantly spike at 100% CPU usage. I created a separate Windows 10 VM using a .raw image instead of .qcow2, and I think that's a little faster.

I tried to include as many details as possible. If you need any other information, please let me know and I'll update my post.